# How to fix Git repo by deleting a commit after a failed rebase attempt?

Tags: git

After unsuccessfully trying to change the author of a commit, I ended up with the following situation in my git repo (local and remote). I am the only developer using this so changing the remote is not really an issue for now. All I would like to do now is 1. to merge the 2 last identical versions and 2. delete the commit on a separate branch that has the wrong author. Is there any way to do this *easily* or should I just leave this as it is to avoid messing this up even more?

[image]

Git status:

```
On branch XXX/YYY
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/XXX/YYY'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Git tree:

```
*   0e2f1b68 (HEAD -> XXX/YYY, origin/XXX/YYY) Merge branch 'XXX/YYY' of (remote URL) into XXX/YYY
|\
| * 6fb3bd33 (refs/original/refs/remotes/origin/XXX/YYY) v1.7.1
* | ef33dfc7 v1.7.1
|/
* e1955fa9 v1.7.0
* e892f48e v1.6.9
* 6b367072 ...
```

I would like to keep `ef33dfc7 v1.7.1` after `e1955fa9 v1.7.0` in the main branch and remove the rest (`6fb3bd33`). I'm using SourceTree and DOS command line and as you probably guessed I am totally new to git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reset the `HEAD` two commits before and make a new commit, which includes the changes of both `0e2f1b68` and `ef33dfc7`, then you delete the branch.

```
git reset --soft HEAD~2
git commit
git branch -D name_of_branch_to_delete
```

To choose what to commit from `HEAD~2`, remove the `--soft` option. In this way the index is restored to `e1955fa9`.

You are rewriting history, but since no one else is working on it, these are safe operations. Before rewriting history (before `reset`), if you are afraid to lose some important changes, creating a temporary backup branch is a good practice:

```
git branch my_backup
```

In the end, to realign the rewritten local branch with the remote one, you need the `--force` option, or simply:

```
git push -f origin XXX/YYY
```

Comment: I didn't delete any branch (I hadn't explicitly branched and didn't know how to delete without knowing the branch name) but after the commit + push situation is as I wanted, thank you! For those using SourceTree: you need to refresh both local and remote repo views to reflect CLI commands.